# Is there a way to let custom sbt plugin discover which platform a Scala project targets?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, sbt-crossproject

I would like to develop an sbt-plugin that would auto-generate sources for Scala projects. The thing is I would like to produce slightly different sources for each targeted platform (JVM, Native, Scala.js).

Because of that, my plugin needs to detect the project platform. I wonder if there is an elegant way of doing that?

Comment: which kind of sources? Scala classes?

Comment: Yeah, for my case these are Scala classes.

Comment: So basically your ask is how to know what platform is it from Scala code, right?

Comment: Yep, from inside the sbt plugin.

Comment: It may be a long answer, but I would explore Scala Meta to parse the sbt config file and to generate new AST based on your platform.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 Could you elaborate on it? How would parsing the sbt config help the generation task to know the type of project that this task is called for?

Comment: take a leek to https://github.com/portable-scala/sbt-crossproject.Maybe it can help

Comment: Hmm, in this case, the project might not even use the `sbt-crossproject` plugin. It might, for example, use only `ScalaJSPlugin` and compile itself only to the Scala.js platform.